# How to embed php code on SMTP relay server

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, exim

I need to develop an SMTP relay service with tracking system, I have already an email marketing system, and it was easy to track delivery, bounces and clicks as the user creates the email in my interface, and the messages comes out my server, so i can track the messages from exim db and also capture the message ID before sending, as I make the message id on the PHPmailer function.

However, the SMTP relay service works kinda different, I gave to my user a email account and password, and he uses this credentials on his CMS or website to send their mail using my server.

I have been researching, with no success, about how to embed PHP code on the SMTP connection, like in this flow

1. CMS or website logs into smtp.anydomainxxyy.com to send an email
2. During the sending I need to capture the message id, the sender email, add a tag somewhere for further tracking and write that to a database. Also I keep track about the number of messages sent

   3. Additionaly, during the sending I need to check if there are messages left to send, if no messages left, deny sending.
   4. If there are messages available, proceed with the sending.
   5. Later with the captured message id, I check against the exim database the delivery status.

If the SMTP service would work like a login website system, I would be able to do this easily, however, I do not even know how the SMTP credential check is made, and I am not quite sure if I can simulate a dummy SMTP server so my users can connect to my script and if the conditions are met my script connect them to the final SMTP server, like this:

1. User connects to dummysmtp.domainxxyy.com (connects so script lets say "smtp.php")
2. script smtp.php validates the credentials, add 1 message to mailcounter, counts if messages left available, and if YES, connects to smtp.domainxxyy.com (The final mail server) and the email is sent.

I would really appreciate any help, I just need to understand how to kinda customize my exim server with php or create my own dummy smtp server so I can build this tracking system, thank you very much

Comment: i cant see how most of this would be possible with php, its simply not the language for it

Comment: I was thinking the same, but, how exim writes the info on the database? I have seen that exim uses like its own programming language, and I am able to track what messages are sent from external clients from the exim db, but would be cool like execute a php script as soon as a user send a message, do you think thats possible? how does sendpulse or sendinblu do the smtp relay system?

Comment: its all doable, but use the right language(s)

Answer (score 0):

Most mail servers allow you to pipe inbound messages into an external script, which can be written in any language. I've used PHP for that before, though lua is probably the best choice in that context. That said, what you're describing sounds like what postfix does with transport maps, i.e. this kind of functionality is probably already built into your mail server if you do a bit of digging in the docs.

Alternatively, look at a natively scriptable mail server, such as [Haraka](https://github.com/haraka/Haraka), which is written in Javascript. You can get it to do all kinds of weird stuff, at any point in the SMTP pipeline, in either direction, and the performance is pretty good too.